# Appending to tuple during for in loop

Tags: python, iterator, tuples

I need to modify a tuple during a `for in` loop, such that the iterator iterates on the tuple.

From my understanding, tuples are immutable; so `tup = tup + (to_add,)` is just reassigning `tup`, not changing the original tuple. So this is tricky.

Here is a test script:

```
tup = ({'abc': 'a'}, {'2': '2'})
blah = True
to_add = {'goof': 'abcde'}
for i in tup:
    if blah:
        tup = tup + (to_add,)
        blah = False
    print(i)
```

Which prints:

```
{'abc': 'a'}
{'2': '2'}
```

What I would like is for it to print:

```
{'abc': 'a'}
{'2': '2'}
{'goof': 'abcde'}
```

From what I understand, I need to "repoint" the implicit tuple iterator mid-script so that it is pointing at the new tuple instead. (I know this is a seriously hacky thing to be doing).

This script accesses the tuple_generator in question:

```
import gc

tup = ({'abc': 'a'}, {'2': '2'})
blah = True
to_add = {'goof': 'abcde'}
for i in tup:
    if blah:
        tup = tup + (to_add,)
        blah = False
        refs = gc.get_referrers(i)
        for ref in refs:
            if type(ref) == tuple and ref != tup:
                refs_to_tup = gc.get_referrers(ref)
                for j in refs_to_tup:
                    if str(type(j)) == "<class 'tuple_iterator'>":
                        tuple_iterator = j

    print(i)
```

How can I modify this tuple_generator so that it points at the new tup, and not the old? Is this even possible?

I am aware that this is a really strange situation, I cannot change that `tup` is a tuple or that I need to use an implicit `for in`, as I am trying to plug into code that I cannot change.

Comment: You can't change the tuple inside the `tuple_iterator` any more than you can change the original tuple. because they're the same tuple. As I already explained in [the answer that you copied this code from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51938335/908494) on your previous question.

Comment: Why not base the looping on the length of the tuple in a while loop? Something like `while i < len(tuple): i += 1`

Comment: I am aware that I cannot change the tuple. I am not trying to change the tuple. I am trying to point tuple_iterator *at the new tuple*. "How can I modify this tuple_generator so that it points at the new tup, and not the old? Is this even possible?"

Comment: No, it's not possible. There is no API on `tuple_iterator` to change the tuple it's referring to, not even a private and undocumented one.

Comment: Why point the iterator to a new tuple? I think your real issue is that you are trying to iterate through a collection while also appending to it, which doesn't work well for iterators.

Comment: I am aware that this is extremely hacky and unconventional. I can't really get into why I want to do this, but if it is impossible I will look for some other solution.

Comment: If you really want to, for CPython, I suppose you could get the C struct underneath the iterator object, cast it to a custom `ctypes.Structure` that's engineered to have the same size as a [`struct seqiterobject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/iterobject.c#L7) (not sure that's the right type, but you should be able to figure it out from there if you want to write this code), and modify the `it_seq`. Of course you'll have to be careful to incref the new value and decref the old one

Comment: ty, I'll look into that.

Comment: Write your own coroutine and `send` the new tuple to add to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way-either portably or specifically within CPython—to do what you're trying to do from within Python, even via undocumented internals of the `tuple_iterator` object. The tuple reference is stored in a variable that isn't exposed to Python, and (unlike the stored index) isn't modified by `__setstate__` or any other method.

However, if you're willing to start monkeying with C pointers behind CPython's back, and you know how to debug the inevitable segfaults…

Under the covers, there's a C struct representing `tuple_iterator`. I think it's either [`seqiterobject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cdbf50cba1664f72ae6621a89c324a32fea70377/Objects/iterobject.c#L7), or a struct with the exact same shape, but you should read through the tupleobject source code to make sure.

Here's what that type looks like in C:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    Py_ssize_t it_index;
    PyObject *it_seq; /* Set to NULL when iterator is exhausted */
} seqiterobject;
```

So, what happens if you create a `ctypes.Structure` subclass that's the same size as this, something like this:

```
class seqiterobject(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('ob_refcnt', ctypes.c_ssize_t),
        ('ob_type', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ('it_index', ctypes.c_ssize_t),
        ('it_seq', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.pyobject)))
```

… and then do this:

```
seqiter = seqiterobject.from_address(id(j))
```

… and then do this:

```
seqiter.it_seq = id(other_tuple)
```

…? Well, you probably corrupt the heap by underreferencing the new value (and also leak the old one), so you'll need to incref the new value and decref the old value first.

But, if you do that… most likely, either it'll segfault the next time you call `__next__`, or it'll work.

If you want more example code that does similar things, see [`superhackyinternals`](https://github.com/abarnert/superhackyinternals). Other than the fact that `seqiterobject` is not even a public type, so this is even *more* hacky, everything else is basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own `coroutine` and send the new tup to it.

```
def coro(iterable):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        try:
            v = next(iterable)
            i = yield v
        except StopIteration:
            break
        if i:
            yield v
            iterable = it.chain(iterable, i)
```

Then this works as you describe:

```
In []:   
blah = True
tup = ({'abc': 'a'}, {'2': '2'})
to_add = {'goof': 'abcde'}

c = coro(tup)
for i in c:
    if blah:
        i = c.send((to_add,))
        blah = False
    print(i)

Out[]:
{'abc': 'a'}
{'2': '2'}
{'goof': 'abcde'}
```

I'm sure there are lots of edge cases I'm missing in the above but it should give you an idea of how it can be done.

Answer (score -1):

Since you plan on modifying the tuple inside the loop, you are probably better off using a while loop keeping track of the current index rather then relying on an iterator. Iterators are only good for looping through collections that do not get added/removed to in the loop.

If you run this below example, the resulting tup object has the items added to it, all while looping through 3 times.

```
tup = ({'abc': 'a'}, {'2': '2'})
blah = True
to_add = {'goof': 'abcde'}

i = 0
while i < len(tup):
    cur = tup[i]
    if blah:
        tup = tup + (to_add,)
        blah = False
    i += 1

print(tup)
```